# Horizontal scroll inside an ion-slide with Ionic 3

Tags: css, scroll, ionic3, horizontal-scrolling, ion-slides

In the image below, I have two Divs, each one is inside an ion-slide, they move horizontally because they are in the ion-slide component (DivA and DivB)

[image]

Inside the DivA (blue), as shown in the image below, I have a Div (DIV-SCROLL) (red) that should have a horizontal scroll as well. However, when trying to scroll on the DIV-SCROLL, the ion-slides moves the entire DivA (blue) to the left.

[image]

What do I do so that the Div DIV-SCROLL has its own horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 2):

Just add css class "swiper-no-swiping" for div with horizontal scroll.
Refer to [SwiperJS api](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api)